# when am trying to upload excel sheet it will uploaded successfully but am getting an error undefined offset: 500 in line 159

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

When I upload an excel sheet it will uploaded successfully but I'm getting an error:

> undefined offset: 500 in line 159

```
    $data = $rows[0];
   
    if(!empty($data) && count($data)){
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if(!empty($value) && $key != 0 && $value[0]){
                
                $product['description'] = $value[500]; //this line causing error undefined offset:500
```

Comment: This is saying that you don't have a value in the array with the key `500`?

Comment: yes, but how i should remove this error

Comment: use ternary operator or Null coalescing to check if the key is set

Answer (score 1):

#### Method: 1

use [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) & check using ternary.

```
$product['description'] = array_key_exists($value[500]) ? $value[500] : default value" ;
```

- Disadvantage:
  array_key_exists() will iterate over the whole array thus has more time complexity.

#### Method: 2

use Null coalescing

```
$product['description'] = $value[500] ?? "default value";
```

(Null coalescing is introduced in PHP 7)

or

```
$product['description'] = isset($value[500]) ? $value[500] : "default value";
```

both will do the same work, just checks for the value for null, but will also return false if the key exists but value in it is null.(you can use `!empty()` for that.)